# Why do we consider special relativity for electrons consider their drift velocity is really small?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, particle-physics

I know that when looking at the electron and a current carrying wire in different inertial frames there will be different kind of forces acting between these two objects. And I know that it is due to length contraction which cause the charge density to change. But I was confused about something that is , we know that the drift velocity is really small compare to speed of light. Why do we still need to consider this special relativistic effect? (If I am not explaining myself clearly please forgive me, sorry)

Comment: The argument you're referring to — that the magnetic force in one reference frame is equivalent to an electric force between length-contracted charges in another reference frame — can be phrased in several different ways. Can you quote the formulation of this relationship that you have in mind? That'll help make your answers clearer.

Comment: What I have in mind is because of length contraction, in some frame the charge density of positive and negative ions are changed between different inertial frames, which make the wire sometimes "neutral" and sometimes "charged". The formulation is using the assumption that charge is conserved between different inertial frames, so that (charge density)*(length)*Area=(new charge density)*(length/gamma)*(Area) result in that (charge density)=(new charge density)/(gamma). I'm just wondering that why do we need to consider this relativistic effect consider the drift velocity of the ions is so small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) If you ignore special relativity altogether, there is no length contraction and so no electrostatic force in the electron frame. Therefore the special relativistic effect, even if it is small, is larger than the (zero) non-relatvisitic effect. This is a general phenomenon: small effects can still be important if the effect that could have been there at zero-th order vanishes.

(b) Even though the force due to *one* non-relativist electron is small, a current carrying wire has a huge number of electrons. This huge number amplifies the effect so that it is macroscopically observable. Again, this is another general effect that can happen, where a small effect becomes large when multiplied by a large parameter, such as (in this case) the number of particles, or (in other cases) the length of time of the experiment.

Comment: Thank you so much!!